# implement OAuth2 on custom database

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

I have a web api application in which I implemented the OAuth2.I have the existing database,the problem is the username is on Users table  and password is on another table say passwordHistory.So how do I validate the username and password and get the token back

Comment: You seem to think it is a problem that the username and password is stored in different tables, can you explain why? I do not see any problem in your setup. Do you have any code to share?

Comment: Of course you will need to have some column(s) in the `passwordHistory` table to uniquely identify the (current) password corresponding to a given username (in the Users table or elsewhere).  Your description of the setup is too brief to suggest what the actual problem here is.

Answer (score 1):

The oAuth specification does not define how the application should (or should not) store the usernames and passwords. Meaning, it is the application (developer) to decide these kind of details.

I see no problem in fetching the data from several tables. I would write a repository layer that does this logic, and can be easily replaced in the future...